# Multidimensional array in Symfony Configuration

Tags: yaml

So I have the following config:

```
shinobi_ui:
application_title: "PILIPINAS"
modules:
    - { name: dashboard, submodules}
    - { name: general }
```

How can i put another array inside each {}.

Let's say submodules is an array like so:

```
 submodules:
    - { name: submodule in dashboard }
    - { name: another submodile}
```

So how can I implement a configuration like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add it inline:

```
shinobi_ui:
application_title: "PILIPINAS"
modules:
    - { name: dashboard, submodules: [{ name: submodule in dashboard }, { name: another submodile}]}
    - { name: general }
```

Or make it multiline:

```
shinobi_ui:
application_title: "PILIPINAS"
modules:
    - name: dashboard
      submodules:
          - { name: submodule in dashboard }
          - { name: another submodile}
    - name: general
```